# php move keys from array into another array

Tags: php, arrays, key

So I have this array:

```
[0] => 3
[1] => 9
[2] => 4
[3] => 6
[4] => 69
[5] => 8
[6] => 9
[7] => 12
[8] => 9
[9] => 7
```

And this one

```
[Far] => 1
[far] => 3
[away] => 1
[behind] => 1
[the] => 23
[word] => 2
[mountains] => 1
[from] => 3
[countries] => 1
[Vokalia] => 1
```

I would like that the values of the first array will overwrite the values of the second array without changing the keys of the second array.
I have already tried fiddling with the `foreach` function, but no prevail.
So in the end I would like it to look like this:

```
[Far] => 3
[far] => 9
[away] => 4
[behind] => 6
[the] => 69
[word] => 8
[mountains] => 9
[from] => 12
[countries] => 9
[Vokalia] => 7
```

does anyone know how to do that? And if yes, can that person give a bit more information how it works in the `foreach` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your arrays are `$array1` and `$array2`:

```
$keys = array_keys($array2);
$result = array_combine($keys, $array1);
```

Documentation:

- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys)
- [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine)

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/103200)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have also tried the array_combine but I did it wrong somewhere. Thanks mate.